# Trouble with this simple trigger script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create trigger personInsertTrigger on dbo.Person for INSERT
as
declare tmpPersonID INT
set tmpPersonID = (select ID from INSERTED)

insert into dbo.PersonRecords values (tmpPersonID, now())
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure
>   personInsertTrigger, Line 3 'INT' is
>   not a recognized CURSOR option. Msg
>   195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure
>   personInsertTrigger, Line 6 'now' is
>   not a recognized built-in function
>   name.

Can anyone help me complete this little script? I want it to save the Person's ID and the time it was inserted into a second table called PersonRecords.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use @ for variables -

```
declare @tmpPersonID INT
```

Local variables must begin with @. Cursors don't use the @ notation, so it is interpreting your declare as a cursor not a variable.

Also instead of `now()` I think you need to use `getdate()`

Answer (score 0):

The variable needs to start with an `@`

Change

```
declare tmpPersonID INT
```

to

```
declare @tmpPersonID INT
```

Have a look at

[DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)